# Problem with Seize "resource choice condition" in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have an agent "customer" with the parameter "BatteryProblem" randomTrue (0.5),
and I have an agent "Technician" with a population of 3. I am trying to assign one technique to solve only "BatteryProblem" and the other two techniques to solve the remaining problems that are not battery related?

**My approach is given below:**

1. Create a variable inside technician agent called problemsSolved of type String.
2. In the main agent, on startup, manually assign what each technician does. Like `technicians(0).problemsSolved = "battery"`.
3. In "custom resource choice" setting.
   Then the incoming agent can choose to only seize resources where `unit.problemsSolved.equals("battery")`. Like this;

**Problem:**
I am having the error
*Description: problemsSolved cannot be resolved or is not a field. Location: tech/Main/seize - Seize*

**Screen Short of my model given below:**

[image]

[image]

Just in case you need any further information feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
((Technician)unit).problemsSolved.equals("battery")
```

Comment: That works thank you. But now it shoes 'Exception during discrete event execution:

NullPointerException' the second i run the model. I think there is no technician in the Seize now that is why it is thronging that error. if that, why?

Comment: because there's no technician when your model starts, exactly

Comment: how can i solve this issue?